# How to calculate the amplitude of a Wien Bridge Oscillator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, wien-bridge

How do I calculate the amplitude of the waveform that is created with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uefas.png) Wien Bridge Oscillator?  My scope measurement shows 1V.  My LTSpice shows ~.8V.

Thank you.

Comment: If your scope shows 1 V, that is the amplitude!

Comment: Yes.  But how do I calculate the amplitude without measurement.  Just using the component values as shown in the diagram?  Is there a method/formula?

Comment: SPICE is the easiest way, and you have used that. Component tolerances will account for the difference.

Comment: Yes I have used Spice.  So there is no formula for calculating the amplitude of a Wien Bridge?  But there must be if Spice does it?

Comment: How well calibrated is the scope probe?

Comment: I don't know the purpose of C1 in your schematic. But to understand the gain part, play around with the value of R3, (make it 21, 20 and 19 k ohm and see what happens.)

Answer (score 1):

***- "But how was 1.2Vpp determined?"***

The stated voltages come from elementary voltage divider rules.

$$V_{out} = V_{R3} + V_{R4}$$

$$\frac{V_{R4}}{V_{R3}} = \frac{R_4}{R_3}$$

$$V_{R4} = \frac{R4}{R3}.V_{R3}$$

The voltage over R3 is capped @ +0.6Vp (positive amplitude) and -0.6Vp (negative amplitude) through the workings of a diode or 1.2Vpp. Since R3,R4 and D1,D2 are located in the feedback loop of the opamp, *Vout* can no longer rise when the voltage is capped and voltage divider rules therefore still apply, at least if you ignore the imperfections of the diode.

$$V_{R4} = \frac{10k}{22k}.{1.2} = 0.54{V_{pp}}$$
$$V_{out} = 1.2 + 0.54 = 1.74V_{pp}$$ or an amplitude of 0.87V.

***- "I assume it is dependent on the V+ rail but how?"***

No, *Vout* is completely independent from the rail voltage and is only determined by the threshold voltage of the diodes.

Some oscillators designs control the closed-loop gain by letting the signal run against the power rail. This provokes clipping and obviously harmonic distortion. However at the exact moment when harmonic distortion starts to set in, the amplitude of the fundamental frequency decreases as energy starts to disperse to the harmonics. This effectively reduces the closed loop gain, causing the oscillator to stabilise itself.

Answer (score 0):

"Yes I have used Spice. So there is no formula for calculating the amplitude of a Wien Bridge?"

- The transfer function of a Wien oscillator is 1/3. To make the closed-loop gain 1 again, gain of the opamp must be set at 3. That's why (R4 + R3)/R4 must be theoretically 3. In your design it is (R3 + R4)/R3 = (22 + 10)/10 = 3.2.
- The diodes d1,d2 function as a closed-loop gain control mechanism and prevent the voltage over R3 to rise above approx. 1.2Vpp, which implies that the voltage over R4 can never be higher than 0.54Vpp (Voltage divider). (1.2 + 0.54)/2 = 0.87V or 0.6Vrms.

Comment: Thank you. There is something I don't understand. Once voltage > forward v of diodes, gain goes to ~ 1.  But how was 1.2Vpp determined? I assume it is dependent on the V+ rail but how?  Also, you have 1.2+.54 = .87? I get 1.74.  I apologize if these seem obvious.  I wish to understand.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: "But how was 1.2Vpp determined?"

Sorry, typo. It's obviously (1.2 + 0.54)/2 = 0.87V. Has been corrected. Answer required to many characters, see next post.